# C#: Get exact substring from HTML code using IndexOf and LastIndexOf

Tags: c#, substring

I have a HTML page retrieved using the `GetResponseStream()` in C#. I need an exact value (`int`) that comes from that page, which is different every time I run the program. Nevertheless, the structure of the HTML code is the same, in particular:

```
 (...) 
 <td colspan="2" class="txtnormal"><div align="right">&nbsp;TAX:</div></td>
 <td class="txtnormal"><div align="right"><strong>0.00</strong></div></td>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td> 
 (...)
```

and

```
 (...) 
     <td colspan="2"><div align="right" class="txtnormal">Total:</div></td>
 <td class="txtnormal"><div align="right"><strong>10.00</strong></div></td>
 <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
 (...)
```

Notice that the code is repeated in the same page (i.e: `<td class="txtnormal"><div align="right"><strong>VALUE</strong></div></td>`), but the title of the values (**TAX** and **Total**) are the only different thing (the actual value could be the same).

I would like to store in a variable the **Total** value, this is: 10.0 **in this case**.

I tried this:

```
int first = responseFromServer.IndexOf("<td class= \"txtnormal\"><div align=\"right\"><strong>") + "<td class=\"txtnormal\"><div align=\"right\"><strong>".Length;
int last = responseFromServer.LastIndexOf("</strong></div></td>");
string value = responseFromServer.Substring(first, last - first);
```

But i get bad results, the value stored in **value** of **ALL** the HTML page **until** the value (is for the difference I´m doing).

Do you know how could I get the exact value, this is: the sub-string between the text I pasted?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To scrape from a page, you have a couple of options. The "best" is to use the DOM to find the node(s) in question and pull it's value. If you can't use the DOM for some reason, you can move to regex and pull the value that way.

Your method is "okay" in many instances, as long as you can be sure the site owner will never set up another instance of `"</strong></div></td>"` anywhere downstream. This is a risky assumption.

What value are you getting for the int string? that will tell you whether or not your particular pattern is working correctly. And I would consider the HTML DOM still, as it is a more accurate way to traverse the nodes.

Comment: I´m getting: `(... a lot of HTML code ... )  <td width="9%"><input type="hidden" name="nunberacc" value="000098800"></td>
     <td colspan="4" class="txtbold Style7"><div align="center"></div></td>
  <td colspan="2"><div align="right" class="txtnormal">Total:</div></td>
  <td class="txtnormal"><div align="right"><strong>10.00`

Comment: Tha means LastIndexof will not work for you. You can iterate with IndexOf and find all of the instances. the one closest to your first value will be the one to use. Or switch to Regex or the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

I think Regex is your friend here:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SimpleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex theRegex = new Regex(@">Total:<.+?<strong>(.+?)</strong>");
            string str = @"<td colspan=""2""><div align=""right"" class=""txtnormal"">Total:</div></td>" +
                     @"<td class=""txtnormal""><div align=""right""><strong>10.00</strong></div></td>" +
                     @"<td colspan=""2"">&nbsp;</td>";
            if (theRegex.Match(str).Success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Total of " + theRegex.Match(str).Result("$1"));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not found");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously your HTML page might have other things that could trip this simple regular expression up but you get the idea.

Comment: Hello: Im trying to replicate this, but with all the HTML response. This is: `string str = @" " + responseFromServer + " ";` But I´m getting false in the `Match(str).Success`. Maybe is because I must double quotes all the ". Could you suggest me an elegant solution for that. I mean: not replacing all the `"`, with `""` (i.e: `string str = @" " + responseFromServer.Replace("\"", "\"\"") + " ";`)